# Как по клику по infoWindows передать конкретный Оbject,

Tags: android

google map заполняется markers из `ArrayList<Object>`, Вопрос в следующем как по клику по infoWindows передать конкретный `Оbject`,

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            Intent route = new Intent(getActivity(), Details.class);
                                route.putExtra("route", route);
                                startActivity(route);
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GoogleMap.addMarker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addMarker%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions%29) возвращает ссылку на добавленный `Marker`. Можно сохранить эту ссылку в отдельную таблицу (типа `HashMap<Marker, YourObject>`), и потом доставать объект.

`GoogleMap` не гарантирует, что объект в `onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)` будет тем же самым, что и объект в `marker = gmap.addMarker(..)`, поэтому для сравнения нужно использовать `marker.equals` (в `HashMap` так и делается).